# How to change URL in WordPress

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am finding the solution since 2 days but still facing issues :(
I also selected from Permalink Settings domain/sample-post/

I am sending the value in GET['id'] variable and receiving this value

i have a URL

mydomain.com/parent-page/child-page/?id=some%20text

i want this

mydomain.com/parent-page/child-page/some%20text

I am using these functions in my functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse12965_query_vars' );
    function wpse12965_query_vars( $query_vars )
    {
        $query_vars[] = 'id';
        return $query_vars;
    }
add_action( 'init', 'wpse12065_init' );
function wpse12065_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'child-page(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?child-page&id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

What is wrong in this code ..? its not working i don't know why.
I also update my .htaccess file on the root

```
RewriteRule ^parent-page/child-page-here/([^/]*)$ /parent-page/child-page-here/?id=$1 [L]
```

When i update the .htaccess files is giving me 500 internal error and when i update the Permalink Settings is automatic removing my REwriteRule from .htaccess files i don't know why its happening.

Please guide me how to solve this issue

Comment: Your regular expression is extremely complicated. What is the problem with using `child-page/(.+)`?

Comment: someone give me the solution so i added this in my files but its not working. Now i solving this problem since two days :( i am new in wordpress thats why its happening

Answer (score 0):

It is atypical to edit `.htaccess` for custom rewrite rules, usually there is no need. WP works on passing *everything* to its PHP core and sorting it out there.

For your specific use case I suspect you would have better lack using [rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). It is quite robust way to handle an extra level in WP URLs and saves a lot of headache, comparing to custom implementation.

Comment: i am new in wordpress..!  Could you please give me the code...?

Comment: Please see the link to documentation in the answer. :)

Comment: how can i write add_rewrite_endpoint into my function.php files could you please tell me